# How does the while loop know when to stop?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm taking Udacity CS101 course (Python). Below is a problem and a solution from "Lesson 2: Problem Set - Find Last"

My question: how does the while loop in the code below know when to stop?

```
# Define a procedure, find_last, that takes as input
# two strings, a search string and a target string,
# and returns the last position in the search string
# where the target string appears, or -1 if there
# are no occurences.
#
# Example: find_last('aaaa', 'a') returns 3

# Make sure your procedure has a return statement.



def find_last(s,t):
     last_pos = -1
     while True:
          pos = s.find(t, last_pos+1)
          if pos == -1:
               return last_pos
          last_pos = pos
```

Comment: Who uses the word `procedure` these days?

Comment: @devnull professors that haven't programmed outside of school since the 70s? :p

Comment: There is a strict definition of *procedure* which however is not fulfilled here, as the function returns a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `while` loop stops when the function exits, and the function exits when the `return` statement is executed.

The `return` statement is executed when `s.find()` returns -1, which means that `t` was no found in `s` when searching from `last_pos + 1` onwards.

Answer (score 1):

It never stops. It is forcibly exited when the `return` statement is executed.

Answer (score 0):

When you `return` from a function, the function's execution is terminated.